# How can I add a border to a widget in Flutter?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, user-interface

I'm using Flutter and I'd like to add a border to a widget (in this case, a `Text` widget).

I tried `TextStyle` and `Text`, but I didn't see how to add a border.

Answer (score 1038, accepted):

You can add the `Text` as a `child` to a `Container` that has a `BoxDecoration` with `border` property:

[image]

```dart
Container(
  margin: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(3.0),
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    border: Border.all(color: Colors.blueAccent)
  ),
  child: Text('My Awesome Border'),
)
```

Answer (score 585):

Here is an expanded answer. A `DecoratedBox` is what you need to add a border, but I am using a `Container` for the convenience of adding margin and padding.

Here is the general setup.

[image]

```
Widget myWidget() {
  return Container(
    margin: const EdgeInsets.all(30.0),
    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
    decoration: myBoxDecoration(), //             <--- BoxDecoration here
    child: Text(
      "text",
      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30.0),
    ),
  );
}
```

where the `BoxDecoration` is

```
BoxDecoration myBoxDecoration() {
  return BoxDecoration(
    border: Border.all(),
  );
}
```

## Border width

[image]

These have a border width of `1`, `3`, and `10` respectively.

```
BoxDecoration myBoxDecoration() {
  return BoxDecoration(
    border: Border.all(
      width: 1, //                   <--- border width here
    ),
  );
}
```

## Border color

[image]

These have a border color of

- `Colors.red`
- `Colors.blue`
- `Colors.green`

Code

```
BoxDecoration myBoxDecoration() {
  return BoxDecoration(
    border: Border.all(
      color: Colors.red, //                   <--- border color
      width: 5.0,
    ),
  );
}
```

## Border side

[image]

These have a border side of

- left (3.0), top (3.0)
- bottom (13.0)
- left (blue[100], 15.0), top (blue[300], 10.0), right (blue[500], 5.0), bottom (blue[800], 3.0)

Code

```
BoxDecoration myBoxDecoration() {
  return BoxDecoration(
    border: Border(
      left: BorderSide( //                   <--- left side
        color: Colors.black,
        width: 3.0,
      ),
      top: BorderSide( //                    <--- top side
        color: Colors.black,
        width: 3.0,
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

## Border radius

[image]

These have border radii of `5`, `10`, and `30` respectively.

```
BoxDecoration myBoxDecoration() {
  return BoxDecoration(
    border: Border.all(
      width: 3.0
    ),
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
        Radius.circular(5.0) //                 <--- border radius here
    ),
  );
}
```

## Going on

[`DecoratedBox`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/DecoratedBox-class.html)/[`BoxDecoration`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/painting/BoxDecoration-class.html) are very flexible. Read [Flutter — BoxDecoration Cheat Sheet](https://medium.com/jlouage/flutter-boxdecoration-cheat-sheet-72cedaa1ba20) for many more ideas.

Comment: Anyone know how to use BorderSide with BorderRadius?

Comment: @HaSnenTai Did you find any solution? In my design i need to give border bottom with pill like shape. How can i achieve this?

Comment: @RobertWilliams, I would use a custom drawing widget.

Comment: @Suragch The widget is Text which needs a strong (pill shaped) border. The text widget width is not fixed. For using custom drawing widget won't I need to provide fix properties?

Comment: @RobertWilliams, I don't know exactly what you are trying to do. I'd open a new question with an illustration and explanation of what isn't currently working. Feel free to link to it from here.

Comment: U can also use the short-hand `BorderRadius.circular(8)` instead of `BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(5.0))`.

Answer (score 37):

**The best way is using BoxDecoration()**

Advantage

- You can set the **border** of a widget
- You can set the border **Color** or **Width**
- You can set a **Rounded corner** of a border
- You can add a **Shadow** of a widget

Disadvantage

- `BoxDecoration` only use with `Container` widget, so you want to wrap your widget  in `Container()`

Example

```
    Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.orange,
        border: Border.all(
            color: Colors.pink[800], // Set border color
            width: 3.0),   // Set border width
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
            Radius.circular(10.0)), // Set rounded corner radius
        boxShadow: [BoxShadow(blurRadius: 10,color: Colors.black,offset: Offset(1,3))] // Make rounded corner of border
      ),
      child: Text("My demo styling"),
    )
```

[image]

Answer (score 35):

You can wrap the widget with `DecoratedBox` which provides decoration :

```
Widget textDecoration(String text){
    return DecoratedBox(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            border: Border.all(
                color: Colors.red,
                width: 10,
            ),
        ),
        child: Text(text)
    );
}
```

Answer (score 28):

**Summary**

I have tried to summarize all the important possibilities when using `border` in `BoxDecoration`.

**Outcomes of the below explained borders:**

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

---

**Explaination**

**Basic**

[image]

```
  Container(
    decoration: BoxDecoration(border: Border.all()),
    child: const Text("Text"),
 ),
```

---

**BorderColor, width and strokeAlign**

[image]

```
Container(
   decoration: BoxDecoration(
   border: Border.all(
       width: 4,
       color: Colors.green,
       strokeAlign: BorderSide.strokeAlignCenter)),
   child: const Text("Text"),
),
```

---

**Border only on specific side**

[image]

```
      Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
        children: [
          Container(
            decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                border: Border(top: BorderSide(width: 2))),
            child: const Text("Text"),
          ),
          Container(
            decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                border: Border(bottom: BorderSide(width: 2))),
            child: const Text("Text"),
          ),
          Container(
            decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                border: Border(
                    top: BorderSide(width: 2),
                    bottom: BorderSide(width: 4))),
            child: const Text("Text"),
          ),
        ],
      ),
```

---

**Different Shapes**

[image]

```
      Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
        children: [
          Container(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                border: Border.all(),
                shape: BoxShape.circle),
            child: const Text("Text"),
          ),
          Container(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              border: Border.all(),
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
            ),
            child: const Text("Text"),
          ),
        ],
      ),
```

---

**Curved Border Radius**

[image]

```
    Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
        children: [
          Container(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                border: Border.all(),
                borderRadius: const BorderRadius.horizontal(
                    left: Radius.circular(5), right: Radius.circular(20))
                ),
            child: const Text("Text"),
          ),
          Container(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                border: Border.all(),
                borderRadius: const BorderRadius.only(
                    topLeft: Radius.circular(10),
                    bottomRight: Radius.circular(20))),
            child: const Text("Text"),
          ),
        ],
      ),
```

Answer (score 21):

As stated in the documentation, Flutter prefers composition over parameters.

Most of the time you're not looking for a property, but instead a wrapper (and sometimes a few helpers/"builder").

For borders, you want `DecoratedBox`, which has a `decoration` property that defines borders; but also background images or shadows.

Alternatively, like [Aziza said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47423297/how-can-i-add-a-border-to-a-widget-in-flutter/47424036#47424036), you can use `Container`. Which is the combination of `DecoratedBox`, `SizedBox` and a few other useful widgets.

Answer (score 13):

Here, as the **[Text](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Text-class.html)** widget does not have a property that allows us to define a `border`, we should wrap it with a widget that allows us to define a border.
There are several solutions.
But the best solution is the use of **[BoxDecoration](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/BoxDecoration-class.html)** in the [Container](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Container-class.html) widget.

**Why choose to use BoxDecoration?**

Because BoxDecoration offers more customization like the possibility to define:

First, the `border` and also define:

- border Color
- border width
- border radius
- shape
- and more ...

**An example:**

```
   Container(
     child:Text(' Hello Word '),
     decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.yellow,
          border: Border.all(
                color: Colors.red ,
                width: 2.0 ,
              ),
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
            ),
          ),
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 9):

Wrap that widget with the container

```
Container(
        margin: const EdgeInsets.all(30.0),
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(border: Border.all(
        color: Colors.black,
        width: 1,
      ),
    ), 
        child: Text(
          "text",
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30.0),
        ),
      );
```

Answer (score 9):

The above answers are also correct, but in case you want to add multiple borders at the same widget, then you can set this

```
Container(
      child: const Center(
        child: Text(
          'This is your Container',
        ),
      ),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
        color: Colors.white,
        boxShadow: const [
          BoxShadow(color: Colors.green, spreadRadius: 8),
          BoxShadow(color: Colors.yellow, spreadRadius: 5),
        ],
      ),
      height: 50,
    )
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

You can use Container to contain your widget:

```
Container(
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    border: Border.all(
    color: Color(0xff000000),
    width: 1,
  )),
  child: Text()
),
```

Comment: This does not anything over the accepted answer from 3 years prior.

Answer (score 5):

Use a container with Boxdercoration.

```
 BoxDecoration(
    border: Border.all(
      width: 3.0
    ),
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0)
  );
```

Comment: This does not anything over the accepted answer from 3 years prior.

Answer (score 4):

In case someone would like a outlined/bordered text or apply multiple borders.

You could try this:

https://pub.dev/packages/outlined_text

[image]

[DEMO](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/1183492137bc71537b24a4a08947fbc4?null_safety=true)

Answer (score 4):

You can use this method for adding border colour for a container.

```
Container(
      height: height * 0.06,
      width: width,
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        border: Border.all(
          color: primaryColor,
        ),
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
      ),
      child: Text(
        "data",
        style: const TextStyle(
          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold
        ),
      ),
    );
```

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve bottom rounded corner  with three side borders.

```
Stack(
children: [
  Container(
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      border: Border.all(color: Colors.red, width: 2),
      borderRadius: const BorderRadius.only(
        topLeft: Radius.zero,
        topRight: Radius.zero,
        bottomLeft: Radius.circular(20),
        bottomRight: Radius.circular(20),
      ),
    ),
    child: Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          const SizedBox(
            height: 1,
          ),
          Text("Dummy text"),
          const SizedBox(
            height: 10,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ),
  Padding(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 2, right: 2),
    child: Container(
      color: AppColors.highLighterBg,
      width: size.width,
      height: 10,
    ),
  )
],
```

);

Answer (score 2):

If you want to add border to some text of container then you can easily to do it by applying BoxDecoration to Container.

code :

```dart
Container(
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    border: Border.all(
      color: Colors.redAccent,
      width: 1,
    ),
  ),
  child: Text('Some Text'),
);
```

Answer (score 2):

**Rounded corner/border with bottom shadow**

```
Container(
 // child it's depend on your requirement
  child: const Center(
    child: Text(
      'This is your Container',
    ),
  ),
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
    color: Colors.white,
  boxShadow: <BoxShadow>[
       // shadow color and radius
        BoxShadow(
            color: Colors.black54,
            blurRadius: 15.0,
            offset: Offset(0.0, 0.75)
        )
      ],
  ),
  // according your height ex. 50
  height: 50,
);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try the following code:

```
Container(
  margin: margin,
  padding: padding,
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    border: Border.all(
      color: color,
      width: width,
    ),
  ),
  child: Text(
    data,
    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30.0),
  ),
),
```

Answer (score 2):

Text border style:

```
Stack(
  children: <Widget>[
    // Stroked text as border.
    Text(
      'Greetings, planet!',
      style: TextStyle(
        fontSize: 40,
        foreground: Paint()
          ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
          ..strokeWidth = 6
          ..color = Colors.blue[700]!,
      ),
    ),
    // Solid text as fill.
    Text(
      'Greetings, planet!',
      style: TextStyle(
        fontSize: 40,
        color: Colors.grey[300],
      ),
    ),
  ],
)
```

Answer (score 1):

use the Text widget inside a container and use decoration to border the text:

```
decoration: BoxDecoration(
    border: Border.all(
    color: Color(0xff000000),
    width: 1,
)),
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there's different approaches for that. One of them is:
Wrap it in a container. And use box decoration like this.

```
Container(
  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    border: Border.all(width: 5, color: Colors.red),
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(50)),
  ), 
  child: const Text(
    "Box decoration",
    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 34.0),
  ),
)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
     In Flutter, you can add a border to a widget using the Container widget and its decoration property. The BoxDecoration class allows you to define various visual elements, including borders.

     import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Border Example'),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: Container(
            width: 200,
            height: 100,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              border: Border.all(
                color: Colors.blue,  // Set border color
                width: 2.0,          // Set border width
              ),
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),  // Set border radius
            ),
            child: Center(
              child: Text(
                'Hello, Border!',
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

Try this solution from latest version of Flutter V3.16
```

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap the widget with container and decorate the container as you want.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).