# border radius not apply inside container widget

Tags: flutter

Border radius not apply inside child `Container`.
Tried with `SizedBox` & `Stack` widget.
I need border view inside container.

```
Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: new Text("ListView"),
  ),
  body: Center(
      child: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
        child: Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0),
                border: Border.all(
                    color: Colors.green,
                    width: 2.0
                )
            ),
            child: Container(
              color: Colors.red,
            )
        ),
      )
  )
)
```

[image]

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Other answers already state that you need to use `ClipRRect` to apply the border radius to the child widget of `Container`.

However, `Container` widget now has its `clipBehaviour` property to clip its child:

```dart
Container(
  // Add the line below
  clipBehavior: Clip.hardEdge,
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0),
    border: Border.all(color: Colors.green, width: 2.0)),
  child: Container(
    color: Colors.red,
  ),
);
```

It's a good pratice to use this property rather than nest the widgets for a clean code.

Comment: This should be accepted answer.

Comment: This is the best answer since using ClipRRect is more processor intensive.

Comment: Perfect answer. Thanks very much. You can't add a boxShadow to the decorator of a ClipRRect. It doesn't work. However, you can add that boxShadow to a Container with clipBehavior Clip.hardEdge. This is another reason why this should be the accepted answer is that.

Comment: you'r great man!

Answer (score 63):

Try this,
Use `ClipRRect` and nest inside another `Container` and now you can add **non-uniform borders**

```
Container(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                      boxShadow: [BoxShadow(color: Colors.black12, blurRadius: 5)],
                    ),
                    child: ClipRRect(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                      child: Container(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          border: Border(
                            left: BorderSide(color: Colors.indigo, width: 5),
                          ),
                        ),
                        child: Column(
                          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Icon(Icons.home),
                            Text("Home"),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  )
```

Answer (score 28):

`decoration` is painted behind the child. If you want the decoration to be applied in front of the container's child, use `foregroundDecoration`

```dart
Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: new Text("ListView"),
  ),
  body: Center(
      child: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
        child: Container(
            foregroundDecoration: BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0),
                border: Border.all(
                    color: Colors.green,
                    width: 2.0
                )
            ),
            child: Container(
              color: Colors.red,
            )
        ),
      )
  )
)
```

above code paints border in front of the child container. Please note that, even with `foregroundDecoration` child container would still have sharp corners.

If you want the child container to have rounded corners, either you need apply `borderRadius` to the child container or use `ClipRRect` with same border radius as the parent container

Answer (score 20):

Instead of

> Container

widget use

> ClipRRect

Before (not working):

```
 Center(
        child: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius: _getAllRoundedBorderRadius(),
          ),
          child: Hero(
            tag: "CossackHero",
            child: TweenImage(
              last: AssetImage("images/background/cossack_0.jpg"),
              first: AssetImage("images/background/c_cossack_0.jpg"),
              duration: 2,
              height: height,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
```

After:

```
Center(
        child: ClipRRect(
          borderRadius: getAllRoundedBorderRadius(),
          child: Hero(
            tag: "CossackHero",
            child: TweenImage(
              last: AssetImage("images/background/cossack_0.jpg"),
              first: AssetImage("images/background/c_cossack_0.jpg"),
              duration: 2,
              height: height,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
```

Answer (score 8):

```dart
const innerRadius = 15.0;
const borderWidth = 2.0;
const borderColor = Colors.green;
const color = Colors.red;
const size = 100.0;

Container(
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(innerRadius + borderWidth),
    color: borderColor,
  ),
  padding: EdgeInsets.all(borderWidth),
  child: ClipRRect(
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(innerRadius),
    child: Container(
      color: color,
      width: size,
      height: size,
    ),
  ),
);
```

This is how it looks:

[image]

And how it works: https://codepen.io/mshibanami/pen/LYyQJXa

---

By the way, some answers suggest you using one `Container` that has `decoration` including `border` and `color` like this:

```dart
Container(
  width: size,
  height: size,
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(innerRadius),
    border: Border.all(
      color: borderColor,
      width: borderWidth,
    ),
    color: color,
  ),
)
```

It's OK but not ideal because the inner color appears slightly outside the border. So when the border is close to the background color, it may stand out like this:

[image]

Answer (score 7):

**Screenshot:**

[image]

---

**With `ClipRRect`** (Using 2 `Container`)

```dart
ClipRRect(
  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16),
  child: Container(
    width: 100,
    height: 100,
    color: Colors.black,
    child: Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.all(8),
      color: Colors.blue,
    ),
  ),
)
```

---

**Without `ClipRRect`** (Using 1 `Container`)

```dart
Container(
  width: 100,
  height: 100,
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16),
    border: Border.all(
      color: Colors.black,
      width: 4,
    ),
    color: Colors.blue,
  ),
)
```

Comment: ClipRRect with borderRadius is the best solution that I found, really thanks :)

Answer (score 5):

Replace your code with this

```
Scaffold(
appBar: AppBar(
title: new Text("ListView"),
),
body: Center(
  child: Padding(
    padding: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
    child: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0),
            border: Border.all(
                color: Colors.green,
                width: 2.0
            )
        ),
        child: Container(
              decoration: new BoxDecoration(borderRadius: 
        BorderRadius.circular(15.0),
                        color: Colors.red,),
                    )
    ),
  )
)
)
```

Comment: Already defined border to parent container. Is it necessary to add again in child container. ? @Zulfiqar

Comment: BorderRadius property defines the shape of the widget, not the line around it. If you use borderRadius on the parent widget, the child doesn't inherit that property, so it paints in the default rectangular shape. If you want it to have rounded borders you have to specify it too.

Answer (score 3):

try

```
decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              gradient: new LinearGradient(
                                begin: Alignment.topCenter,
                                end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                                stops: [0.02, 0.02],
                                colors: [Colors.red, Colors.white],
                              ),
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10)),
                              color: Colors.white,
                              boxShadow: [
                                BoxShadow(color: Colors.grey, blurRadius: 5.0),
                              ],
                            ),
```

Comment: Why use gradient and how does this answer the question?

Answer (score 2):

you have to just add these line of code **clipBehavior:Clip.hardEdge,**

```
Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: new Text("ListView"),
  ),
  body: Center(
      child: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
        child: Container(
```

> [clipBehavior:Clip.hardEdge,](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W3IfL.png)

```
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0),
                border: Border.all(
                    color: Colors.green,
                    width: 2.0
                )
            ),
            child: Container(
              color: Colors.red,
            )
        ),
      )
  )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess your container might just not be visible because it has no child/height/width.

Try adding some `Text` as a child or if you want it to expand, you can force with [SizedBox.expand](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/SizedBox/SizedBox.expand.html).

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47424036/7829326) for example on borders.

Comment: Border is visible. Issue with border radius for child widget.Here is  image link http://putul.io/JWDFnTYTl. In child widget not applied parent widget border which one i gave. @MarcinSzałek