# How to set rounded border to a MaterialButton on Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, widget

I'm trying set rounded border to my `MaterialButton`, to do it I'm setting a `RoundedRectangleBorder` to shape attribute's `MaterialButton`, the problem is that it's not have effect.

**Code:**

```
  Widget _showNeedHelpButton() {
    return new Padding(      
      padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0.0, 5.0, 0.0, 0.0),
      child: new MaterialButton(
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20.0))),
        elevation: 5.0,
        minWidth: 200.0,
        height: 35,
        color: Color(0xFF801E48),
        child: new Text('Preciso de ajuda',
            style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0, color: Colors.white)),
        onPressed: () {
          setState(() {
            _isNeedHelp = true;
          });
        },
      ),
    );
  }
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: May I ask how much your question differs from this problem?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47423297/how-do-i-add-a-border-to-a-widget-in-flutter/47424036#47424036

Comment: The `MaterialButton` Widget have a `shape` attribute, and I want use it, not other widget like `Container`.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

If you need to use `MaterialButton()` - You need to Warp the button with `Material` Widget, to get the desired behavior.

```
    Widget _showNeedHelpButton() {
    return Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0.0, 5.0, 0.0, 0.0),
      child: Material(  //Wrap with Material
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius:BorderRadius.circular(22.0) ),
        elevation: 18.0,
        color: Color(0xFF801E48),
        clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias, // Add This
        child: MaterialButton(
          minWidth: 200.0,
          height: 35,
          color: Color(0xFF801E48),
          child: new Text('Preciso de ajuda',
              style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0, color: Colors.white)),
          onPressed: () {
//          setState(() {
//            _isNeedHelp = true;
//          });
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Output:
[image]

UPDATE:

```
  minWidth: 200.0,
  height: 95,
```

[image]

Comment: Why `shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius:BorderRadius.circular(22.0) )` not works without wrap?

Comment: most likely they will remove it  from the MaterialButton in future updates.

Comment: I can change height and width?

Comment: @Augusto  what doesn't work - ? i used height & width. worked fine. i even updated answer.

Comment: it's works now... But it works if height > 30.0. if `height = 10.0` for example, not changes happens...

Comment: add - `materialTapTargetSize: MaterialTapTargetSize.shrinkWrap,` in button

Answer (score 9):

```
MaterialButton(
        child: Text('My Button'),
        height: 40,
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
        ),
)
```

RoundedRectangleBorder
will help you https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/RoundedRectangleBorder-class.html

Answer (score 3):

You should set the shape for MaterialButton and borderRadius for Material to make it round even when animation tab:

```
Material(
  elevation: 10.0,
  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),//12
  color: Colors.transparent,//Colors.cyan.withOpacity(0.5),
  child: MaterialButton(
    minWidth: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
    color: Colors.cyan.withOpacity(0.7),
    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius:BorderRadius.circular(30.0) ),
    splashColor: Colors.cyan,
    onPressed: () async {},
    child: Text('Login',
        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
        style: TextStyle(
          fontSize: 18.0,
          color: Colors.black,
          fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
          //fontFamily: lang.font
        )),
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried wrapping it within a `ClipRRect()` ?

```
ClipRRect(
  borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20.0)),
  child: MaterialButton(...),
),
```

You can find the documentation here: [ClipRRect()](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/ClipRRect-class.html)

Comment: There are infinte ways to make a border radius circular, I want use `shape` attribute of `MaterialButton`.

Comment: You probably have to go for a workaround as this seems to be an unfixed issue with flutter. [https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/24225](Github #24225)  
  
What is the reason for sticking with `MaterialButton()` ?