# How to add separator between leading icon and text in textfield in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation, flutter-listview

how to add separator or divider in between text and leading ico 
[image]

```
 TextField(
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.perm_identity ),
            labelText: 'Enter Your Name',
          )
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to wrap the Icon in a container and add a border to it.

```
Container(
  margin: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(3.0),
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    border: Border(left: 
        BorderSide( //                   <--- left side
            color: Colors.black,
            width: 3.0,
        ),
      ),
      child: Icon(Icons.perm_identity),
    ),
),
```

#### References

- [Great answer for borders](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53680045/4712391)
- [Box Decoration Cheat sheet](https://medium.com/jlouage/flutter-boxdecoration-cheat-sheet-72cedaa1ba20)