# change theme of DatePickerTimeline Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, datepicker

I am new to Flutter. I am using DatePickerTimeline package (https://pub.dev/packages/date_picker_timeline) . I want to change theme of my DatePicker widget. In first picture you will see what I achieved. But I want my custom design like adding color to border to boxes.

This is the first picture

[image: this is first picture]

In the second picture you will see what I want to do. And I would like to ask can I make half box like in second picture

Second picture

[image: Second picture]

Comment: This is the place. https://github.com/iamvivekkaushik/DatePickerTimelineFlutter/blob/e01b6806716d684c5d890cf2bc4e06ae317e0efc/lib/date_widget.dart#L46-L53 I am new to flutter too. But looking at that, maybe it's possible to just change the text styles (to hide the small labels) without making changes to the package, but for me it would probably be easier to just fork and throw in a container and BoxDecoration border

Comment: Probably replace the Column with a container. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47423297/how-to-add-a-border-to-a-widget-in-flutter

Comment: I am already using Container.