# Adding just a left side border decoration

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm aware of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47423297/how-can-i-add-a-border-to-a-widget-in-flutter) how to assign a border to e.g. a `Container`.

Unfortunately, I failed to find a hint how to only draw the left edge of a `Container` as a border.

**How to assign a border only to one edge of a `Widget` / `Container`?**

Comment: Can you include an attachment what you are trying to archive,  my guesses have been answer on that link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add one side border like so

```dart
Container(
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
     border: Border(left: BorderSide(width: 1, color: Colors.red)
  ),
  child: //...,
)
```

There are also right, top, and bottom params