# Flutter: UI issues with sign up UI (Lift the sign up box to top and add a box to phone number pin code)

Tags: flutter

**I am trying to create a sign-up UI like below:**

[image]

**Below is my developed UI:**

[image]

**My Code:**

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            SizedBox(
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
              child: Stack(children: <Widget>[
                Positioned(
                    child: Container(
                      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.4,
                      color: const Color(0xff32394a),
                      child: Center(
                          child: MaterialButton(
                              onPressed: () {},
                              child: const Text(
                                'AppName',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 40,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                    color: Colors.white
                                ),
                              ))),
                    )),
                Positioned(
                    top: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.4 - 100,
                    left: 32,
                    right: 32,
                    child: Column(
                      children: [
                        Container(
                          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width - 64,
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            color: const Color(0xffFFFFFF),
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                            border: Border.all(
                              color: const Color(0xffe8e8e8),  // Set the border color here
                              width: 2.0,        // Set the border width
                            ),
                          ),
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(32),
                          child: Column(
                            children: [
                              Container(
                                margin: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 32),
                                child: const Text(
                                  'Sign Up',
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 24,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                              Container(
                                margin: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 16),
                                child: TextField(
                                  cursorColor: const Color(0x9932394a),
                                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                                      focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                        borderSide: BorderSide(color: const Color(0x9932394a)),
                                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16),
                                      ),
                                      border: OutlineInputBorder(
                                          borderRadius:
                                          BorderRadius.circular(16)),
                                      hintText: 'Full Name',
                                      hintStyle: TextStyle(color: const Color(0x99d1d1d1)),
                                      contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                          left: 16,
                                          right: 16,
                                          top: 8,
                                          bottom: 8)),
                                ),
                              ),
                              Container(
                                margin: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 16),
                                child: TextField(
                                  cursorColor: const Color(0x9932394a),
                                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                                      focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                        borderSide: BorderSide(color: const Color(0x9932394a)),
                                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16),
                                      ),
                                      border: OutlineInputBorder(
                                          borderRadius:
                                          BorderRadius.circular(16)),
                                      hintText: 'Email',
                                      hintStyle: TextStyle(color: const Color(0x99d1d1d1)),
                                      contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                          left: 16,
                                          right: 16,
                                          top: 8,
                                          bottom: 8)),
                                ),
                              ),
                              Container(
                                margin: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 16),
                                child: TextField(
                                  cursorColor: const Color(0x9932394a),
                                  keyboardType: TextInputType.phone,
                                  maxLength: 10,
                                  maxLengthEnforcement: MaxLengthEnforcement.enforced,
                                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                                      prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.arrow_drop_down),
                                      labelText: '+1',
                                      suffixIconColor: const Color(0x9932394a),
                                      focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                        borderSide: BorderSide(color: const Color(0x9932394a)),
                                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16),
                                      ),
                                      border: OutlineInputBorder(
                                          borderRadius:
                                          BorderRadius.circular(16)),
                                      hintText: 'Phone Number',
                                      hintStyle: TextStyle(color: const Color(0x99d1d1d1)),
                                      contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                          left: 16,
                                          right: 16,
                                          top: 8,
                                          bottom: 8)),
                                ),
                              ),
                              Container(
                                margin: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 16),
                                child: TextField(
                                  cursorColor: const Color(0x9932394a),
                                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                                      focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                        borderSide: BorderSide(color: const Color(0x9932394a)),
                                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16),
                                      ),
                                      border: OutlineInputBorder(
                                          borderRadius:
                                          BorderRadius.circular(16)),
                                      hintText: 'Username',
                                      hintStyle: TextStyle(color: const Color(0x99d1d1d1)),
                                      contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                          left: 16,
                                          right: 16,
                                          top: 8,
                                          bottom: 8)),
                                ),
                              ),
                              Container(
                                margin: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 20),
                                child: TextField(
                                  cursorColor: const Color(0x9932394a),
                                  controller: password_textfield,
                                  obscureText: !_passwordVisible,
                                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                                      focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                        borderSide: BorderSide(color: const Color(0x9932394a)),
                                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16),
                                      ),
                                      border: OutlineInputBorder(
                                          borderRadius:
                                          BorderRadius.circular(16)),
                                      hintText: 'Password',
                                      hintStyle: TextStyle(color: const Color(0x99d1d1d1)),
                                      suffixIcon: IconButton(
                                        icon: Icon(
                                          // Based on passwordVisible state choose the icon
                                          _passwordVisible
                                              ? Icons.visibility
                                              : Icons.visibility_off,
                                          color: const Color(0x9932394a),
                                        ),
                                        onPressed: () {
                                          // Update the state i.e. toogle the state of passwordVisible variable
                                          setState(() {
                                            _passwordVisible = !_passwordVisible;
                                          });
                                        },
                                      ),
                                      contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                          left: 16,
                                          right: 16,
                                          top: 8,
                                          bottom: 8)),
                                ),
                              ),
                              Container(
                                margin: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 20),
                                child: TextField(
                                  cursorColor: const Color(0x9932394a),
                                  controller: confirm_password_textfield,
                                  obscureText: !_confirmpasswordVisible,
                                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                                      focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                        borderSide: BorderSide(color: const Color(0x9932394a)),
                                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16),
                                      ),
                                      border: OutlineInputBorder(
                                          borderRadius:
                                          BorderRadius.circular(16)),
                                      hintText: 'Confirm Password',
                                      hintStyle: TextStyle(color: const Color(0x99d1d1d1)),
                                      suffixIcon: IconButton(
                                        icon: Icon(
                                          // Based on passwordVisible state choose the icon
                                          _confirmpasswordVisible
                                              ? Icons.visibility
                                              : Icons.visibility_off,
                                          color: const Color(0x9932394a),
                                        ),
                                        onPressed: () {
                                          // Update the state i.e. toogle the state of passwordVisible variable
                                          setState(() {
                                            _confirmpasswordVisible = !_confirmpasswordVisible;
                                          });
                                        },
                                      ),
                                      contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                          left: 16,
                                          right: 16,
                                          top: 8,
                                          bottom: 8)),
                                ),
                              ),
                              Row(

                                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                                children: [
                                  Expanded(
                                    child: ElevatedButton(
                                      onPressed: () {
                                        StartRegistration();
                                      },
                                      style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                                        backgroundColor: const Color(0x9932394a),
                                        minimumSize: Size(double.infinity, 50),
                                        textStyle: TextStyle(
                                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                            fontSize: 18
                                        ),
                                        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20), // Adjust the value as per your requirement
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                      child: const Text("Register",
                                          style: TextStyle(
                                            color: Colors.white,
                                          )),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                              const SizedBox(
                                height: 25,
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                        Container(
                          margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 32),
                          child: TextButton(
                            onPressed: () async{
                              Navigator.of(context).pop();
                            },
                            child: RichText(
                              text: TextSpan(
                                children: <TextSpan>[
                                  TextSpan(
                                    text: "Back to",
                                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 15.0),
                                  ),
                                  TextSpan(
                                    text: ' Sign In',
                                    style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, color: Colors.black, fontSize: 15.0),
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        )
                      ],
                    )),
              ]),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

I am facing 2 issues:

1. I need to move the "AppName" text to top then lift the sign up box to top and make visible the "Back to Sign In" text.
2. Also I need to add a box for the phone number pin code like the top image. Hint text also I need to show initially, currently after highlighting the `TextField` only it is visible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have modified your code as per your needs.
The following is my `main.dart` file and you can view the [code here](https://dartpad.dev/?id=0d01433ac9f74f57857db03335483ad0).

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(seedColor: Colors.deepPurple),
        useMaterial3: true,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  final password_textfield = TextEditingController();

  final confirm_password_textfield = TextEditingController();

  late List<String> countryCodes;
  String _countryCode = "+1";

  bool _passwordVisible = false;

  bool _confirmpasswordVisible = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    countryCodes = [];
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
      countryCodes.add("+$i");
    }
  }

  void StartRegistration() {}

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            SizedBox(
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
              child: Stack(children: <Widget>[
                Positioned(
                    child: Container(
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.4,
                  color: const Color(0xff32394a),
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      const SizedBox(
                        height: kToolbarHeight + 10,
                      ),
                      Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: [
                          const Padding(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.only(left:8.0),
                            child: Icon(Icons.chevron_left,color: Colors.white,size: 48,),
                          ),
                          MaterialButton(
                              onPressed: () {},
                              child: const Text(
                                'AppName',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 40,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                    color: Colors.white),
                              )),
                          const SizedBox(width: 56,), // for row layout spacing (icon + padding)
                        ],
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                )),
                Positioned(
                    top: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.4 - 200,
                    left: 32,
                    right: 32,
                    child: Column(
                      children: [
                        Container(
                          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width - 64,
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            color: const Color(0xffFFFFFF),
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                            border: Border.all(
                              color: const Color(0xffe8e8e8),
                              // Set the border color here
                              width: 2.0, // Set the border width
                            ),
                          ),
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(32),
                          child: Column(
                            children: [
                              Container(
                                margin: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 32),
                                child: const Text(
                                  'Sign Up',
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 24,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                              Container(
                                margin: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 16),
                                child: TextField(
                                  cursorColor: const Color(0x9932394a),
                                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                                      focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                        borderSide: const BorderSide(
                                            color: Color(0x9932394a)),
                                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16),
                                      ),
                                      border: OutlineInputBorder(
                                          borderRadius:
                                              BorderRadius.circular(16)),
                                      hintText: 'Full Name',
                                      hintStyle: const TextStyle(
                                          color: Color(0x99d1d1d1)),
                                      contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                          left: 16,
                                          right: 16,
                                          top: 8,
                                          bottom: 8)),
                                ),
                              ),
                              Container(
                                margin: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 16),
                                child: TextField(
                                  cursorColor: const Color(0x9932394a),
                                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                                      focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                        borderSide: const BorderSide(
                                            color: Color(0x9932394a)),
                                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16),
                                      ),
                                      border: OutlineInputBorder(
                                          borderRadius:
                                              BorderRadius.circular(16)),
                                      hintText: 'Email',
                                      hintStyle: const TextStyle(
                                          color: Color(0x99d1d1d1)),
                                      contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                          left: 16,
                                          right: 16,
                                          top: 8,
                                          bottom: 8)),
                                ),
                              ),
                              Container(
                                margin: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 16),
                                child: TextField(
                                  cursorColor: const Color(0x9932394a),
                                  keyboardType: TextInputType.phone,
                                  maxLength: 10,
                                  maxLengthEnforcement:
                                      MaxLengthEnforcement.enforced,
                                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                                      prefixIcon: Row(
                                        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                                        children: [
                                          DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
                                            child: Container(
                                              margin: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                                  left: 16, right: 16),
                                              padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                                                  top: 2, bottom: 2),
                                              decoration: const ShapeDecoration(
                                                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                                    side: BorderSide(
                                                        width: 1.0,
                                                        style:
                                                            BorderStyle.solid),
                                                    borderRadius:
                                                        BorderRadius.all(
                                                            Radius.circular(
                                                                5.0)),
                                                  ),
                                                  color: Color.fromRGBO(
                                                      240, 240, 240, 1)),
                                              child: DropdownButton(
                                                itemHeight: null,
                                                borderRadius:
                                                    const BorderRadius.all(
                                                        Radius.circular(16)),
                                                value: _countryCode,
                                                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                                    left: 16),
                                                isDense: true,
                                                items: countryCodes.map((e) {
                                                  return DropdownMenuItem<
                                                      String>(
                                                    value: e,
                                                    child: Text(e),
                                                  );
                                                }).toList(),
                                                onChanged: (dynamic value) {
                                                  setState(() {
                                                    _countryCode = value;
                                                  });
                                                },
                                              ),
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                        ],
                                      ),
                                      suffixIconColor: const Color(0x9932394a),
                                      focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                        borderSide: const BorderSide(
                                            color: Color(0x9932394a)),
                                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16),
                                      ),
                                      border: OutlineInputBorder(
                                          borderRadius:
                                              BorderRadius.circular(16)),
                                      hintText: 'Phone Number',
                                      hintStyle: const TextStyle(
                                          color: Color(0x99d1d1d1)),
                                      contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                          left: 16,
                                          right: 16,
                                          top: 8,
                                          bottom: 8)),
                                ),
                              ),
                              Container(
                                margin: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 16),
                                child: TextField(
                                  cursorColor: const Color(0x9932394a),
                                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                                      focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                        borderSide: const BorderSide(
                                            color: Color(0x9932394a)),
                                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16),
                                      ),
                                      border: OutlineInputBorder(
                                          borderRadius:
                                              BorderRadius.circular(16)),
                                      hintText: 'Username',
                                      hintStyle: const TextStyle(
                                          color: Color(0x99d1d1d1)),
                                      contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                          left: 16,
                                          right: 16,
                                          top: 8,
                                          bottom: 8)),
                                ),
                              ),
                              Container(
                                margin: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 20),
                                child: TextField(
                                  cursorColor: const Color(0x9932394a),
                                  controller: password_textfield,
                                  obscureText: !_passwordVisible,
                                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                                      focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                        borderSide: const BorderSide(
                                            color: Color(0x9932394a)),
                                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16),
                                      ),
                                      border: OutlineInputBorder(
                                          borderRadius:
                                              BorderRadius.circular(16)),
                                      hintText: 'Password',
                                      hintStyle: const TextStyle(
                                          color: Color(0x99d1d1d1)),
                                      suffixIcon: IconButton(
                                        icon: Icon(
                                          // Based on passwordVisible state choose the icon
                                          _passwordVisible
                                              ? Icons.visibility
                                              : Icons.visibility_off,
                                          color: const Color(0x9932394a),
                                        ),
                                        onPressed: () {
                                          // Update the state i.e. toogle the state of passwordVisible variable
                                          setState(() {
                                            _passwordVisible =
                                                !_passwordVisible;
                                          });
                                        },
                                      ),
                                      contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                          left: 16,
                                          right: 16,
                                          top: 8,
                                          bottom: 8)),
                                ),
                              ),
                              Container(
                                margin: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 20),
                                child: TextField(
                                  cursorColor: const Color(0x9932394a),
                                  controller: confirm_password_textfield,
                                  obscureText: !_confirmpasswordVisible,
                                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                                      focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                        borderSide: const BorderSide(
                                            color: Color(0x9932394a)),
                                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16),
                                      ),
                                      border: OutlineInputBorder(
                                          borderRadius:
                                              BorderRadius.circular(16)),
                                      hintText: 'Confirm Password',
                                      hintStyle: const TextStyle(
                                          color: Color(0x99d1d1d1)),
                                      suffixIcon: IconButton(
                                        icon: Icon(
                                          // Based on passwordVisible state choose the icon
                                          _confirmpasswordVisible
                                              ? Icons.visibility
                                              : Icons.visibility_off,
                                          color: const Color(0x9932394a),
                                        ),
                                        onPressed: () {
                                          // Update the state i.e. toogle the state of passwordVisible variable
                                          setState(() {
                                            _confirmpasswordVisible =
                                                !_confirmpasswordVisible;
                                          });
                                        },
                                      ),
                                      contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                          left: 16,
                                          right: 16,
                                          top: 8,
                                          bottom: 8)),
                                ),
                              ),
                              Row(
                                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                                children: [
                                  Expanded(
                                    child: ElevatedButton(
                                      onPressed: () {
                                        StartRegistration();
                                      },
                                      style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                                        backgroundColor:
                                            const Color(0x9932394a),
                                        minimumSize:
                                            const Size(double.infinity, 50),
                                        textStyle: const TextStyle(
                                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                            fontSize: 18),
                                        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(
                                              20), // Adjust the value as per your requirement
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                      child: const Text("Register",
                                          style: TextStyle(
                                            color: Colors.white,
                                          )),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                              const SizedBox(
                                height: 25,
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                        Container(
                          margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 32),
                          child: TextButton(
                            onPressed: () async {
                              Navigator.of(context).pop();
                            },
                            child: RichText(
                              text: const TextSpan(
                                children: <TextSpan>[
                                  TextSpan(
                                    text: "Back to",
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                        color: Colors.black, fontSize: 15.0),
                                  ),
                                  TextSpan(
                                    text: ' Sign In',
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                        color: Colors.black,
                                        fontSize: 15.0),
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        )
                      ],
                    )),
              ]),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Here is the screenshot.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Kk web's code with some slight changes:

```
  final TextEditingController confirmPassController = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController passController = TextEditingController();

  final TextEditingController phoneController = TextEditingController();

  bool _showPass = false;
  bool _showConfirmPass = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    double width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: const Color(0xff32394a),
        centerTitle: true,
        title: const Text("AppName"),
        titleTextStyle:
            const TextStyle(fontSize: 26, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Stack(
          clipBehavior: Clip.none,
          children: [
            Container(
              width: width,
              height: height * .30,
              color: const Color(0xff32394a),
            ),
            Center(
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  Container(
                    margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: kToolbarHeight / 3),
                    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * .85,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: const Color(0xffFFFFFF),
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                      border: Border.all(
                        color: const Color(0xffe8e8e8),
                        // Set the border color here
                        width: 2.0, // Set the border width
                      ),
                    ),
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(32),
                    child: Column(
                      children: [
                        Container(
                          margin: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 32),
                          child: const Text(
                            'Sign Up',
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 24,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        Container(
                          margin: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 16),
                          child: TextField(
                            cursorColor: const Color(0x9932394a),
                            decoration: InputDecoration(
                                focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                  borderSide: const BorderSide(
                                      color: Color(0x9932394a)),
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16),
                                ),
                                border: OutlineInputBorder(
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16)),
                                hintText: 'Full Name',
                                hintStyle:
                                    const TextStyle(color: Color(0x99d1d1d1)),
                                contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                    left: 16, right: 16, top: 8, bottom: 8)),
                          ),
                        ),
                        Container(
                          margin: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 16),
                          child: TextField(
                            cursorColor: const Color(0x9932394a),
                            decoration: InputDecoration(
                                focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                  borderSide: const BorderSide(
                                      color: Color(0x9932394a)),
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16),
                                ),
                                border: OutlineInputBorder(
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16)),
                                hintText: 'Email',
                                hintStyle:
                                    const TextStyle(color: Color(0x99d1d1d1)),
                                contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                    left: 16, right: 16, top: 8, bottom: 8)),
                          ),
                        ),
                        Container(
                          margin: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 16),
                          child: TextField(
                            cursorColor: const Color(0x9932394a),
                            keyboardType: TextInputType.phone,
                            maxLength: 10,
                            controller: phoneController,
                            maxLengthEnforcement: MaxLengthEnforcement.enforced,
                            decoration: InputDecoration(
                                prefixIcon: Container(
                                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10),
                                  margin: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                                  height: 10,
                                  width: 65,
                                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
                                      color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.10),
                                      border: Border.all(
                                        color: Colors.black,
                                      )),
                                  child: const Row(
                                    children: [
                                      Text("+1"),
                                      Icon(Icons.arrow_drop_down),
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                ),
                                suffixIconColor: const Color(0x9932394a),
                                focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                  borderSide: const BorderSide(
                                      color: Color(0x9932394a)),
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16),
                                ),
                                border: OutlineInputBorder(
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16)),
                                hintText: 'Phone Number',
                                counterText: "",
                                hintStyle:
                                    const TextStyle(color: Color(0x99d1d1d1)),
                                contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                    left: 16, right: 16, top: 8, bottom: 8)),
                          ),
                        ),
                        Container(
                          margin: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 16),
                          child: TextField(
                            cursorColor: const Color(0x9932394a),
                            decoration: InputDecoration(
                                focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                  borderSide: const BorderSide(
                                      color: Color(0x9932394a)),
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16),
                                ),
                                border: OutlineInputBorder(
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16)),
                                hintText: 'Username',
                                hintStyle:
                                    const TextStyle(color: Color(0x99d1d1d1)),
                                contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                    left: 16, right: 16, top: 8, bottom: 8)),
                          ),
                        ),
                        Container(
                          margin: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 20),
                          child: TextField(
                            cursorColor: const Color(0x9932394a),
                            controller: passController,
                            obscureText: !_showPass,
                            decoration: InputDecoration(
                                focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                  borderSide: const BorderSide(
                                      color: Color(0x9932394a)),
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16),
                                ),
                                border: OutlineInputBorder(
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16)),
                                hintText: 'Password',
                                hintStyle:
                                    const TextStyle(color: Color(0x99d1d1d1)),
                                suffixIcon: IconButton(
                                  icon: Icon(
                                    // Based on passwordVisible state choose the icon
                                    _showPass
                                        ? Icons.visibility
                                        : Icons.visibility_off,
                                    color: const Color(0x9932394a),
                                  ),
                                  onPressed: () {
                                    // Update the state i.e. toogle the state of passwordVisible variable
                                    setState(() {
                                      _showPass = !_showPass;
                                    });
                                  },
                                ),
                                contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                    left: 16, right: 16, top: 8, bottom: 8)),
                          ),
                        ),
                        Container(
                          margin: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 20),
                          child: TextField(
                            cursorColor: const Color(0x9932394a),
                            controller: confirmPassController,
                            obscureText: !_showConfirmPass,
                            decoration: InputDecoration(
                                focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                  borderSide: const BorderSide(
                                      color: Color(0x9932394a)),
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16),
                                ),
                                border: OutlineInputBorder(
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16)),
                                hintText: 'Confirm Password',
                                hintStyle:
                                    const TextStyle(color: Color(0x99d1d1d1)),
                                suffixIcon: IconButton(
                                  icon: Icon(
                                    // Based on passwordVisible state choose the icon
                                    _showConfirmPass
                                        ? Icons.visibility
                                        : Icons.visibility_off,
                                    color: const Color(0x9932394a),
                                  ),
                                  onPressed: () {
                                    // Update the state i.e. toogle the state of passwordVisible variable
                                    setState(() {
                                      _showConfirmPass =
                                          !_showConfirmPass;
                                    });
                                  },
                                ),
                                contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                    left: 16, right: 16, top: 8, bottom: 8)),
                          ),
                        ),
                        MaterialButton(
                          onPressed: () {},
                          color: const Color(0xff32394a),
                          minWidth: width,
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
                          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
                          ),
                          child: const Text("Register",style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white,fontSize: 16),),
                        ),
                        const SizedBox(
                          height: 25,
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: kToolbarHeight * .30),
                    child: TextButton(
                      onPressed: () async {
                        Navigator.of(context).pop();
                      },
                      child: RichText(
                        text: const TextSpan(
                          children: <TextSpan>[
                            TextSpan(
                              text: "Back to",
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.black, fontSize: 15.0),
                            ),
                            TextSpan(
                              text: ' Sign In',
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                  color: Colors.black,
                                  fontSize: 15.0),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

[DEMO](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LRxP1.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the result via below code

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
      body: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          Positioned(
            child: Column(
              children: [
                Container(
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.4,
                  color: const Color(0xff32394a),
                ),
                Container(
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.6,
                  color: const Color(0xffffffff),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Positioned(
            top: 0,
            bottom: 0,
            right: 0,
            left: 0,
            child: SafeArea(
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  Container(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 30),
                    child: Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: [
                        Expanded(
                          child: Icon(
                            (Icons.arrow_back_ios),
                            color: Colors.white,
                          ),
                          flex: 1,
                        ),
                        Expanded(
                          child: Text(
                            'AppName',
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 40,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              color: Colors.white,
                            ),
                            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                          ),
                          flex: 4,
                        ),
                        Expanded(child: SizedBox())
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 20,
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    child: SingleChildScrollView(

                        physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
                        child: Container(
                          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width - 64,

                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            color: const Color(0xffFFFFFF),
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                            border: Border.all(
                              color: const Color(0xffe8e8e8),
                              // Set the border color here
                              width: 2.0, // Set the border width
                            ),
                          ),
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(32),
                          child: Padding(

                            padding:   EdgeInsets.only(bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom),
                            child: Column(
                              children: [
                                Container(
                                  margin: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 32),
                                  child: const Text(
                                    'Sign Up',
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                      fontSize: 24,
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                                Container(
                                  margin: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 16),
                                  child: TextField(
                                    cursorColor: const Color(0x9932394a),
                                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                                        focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                          borderSide: BorderSide(
                                              color: const Color(0x9932394a)),
                                          borderRadius:
                                              BorderRadius.circular(16),
                                        ),
                                        border: OutlineInputBorder(
                                            borderRadius:
                                                BorderRadius.circular(16)),
                                        hintText: 'Full Name',
                                        hintStyle: TextStyle(
                                            color: const Color(0x99d1d1d1)),
                                        contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                            left: 16,
                                            right: 16,
                                            top: 8,
                                            bottom: 8)),
                                  ),
                                ),
                                Container(
                                  margin: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 16),
                                  child: TextField(
                                    cursorColor: const Color(0x9932394a),
                                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                                        focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                          borderSide: BorderSide(
                                              color: const Color(0x9932394a)),
                                          borderRadius:
                                              BorderRadius.circular(16),
                                        ),
                                        border: OutlineInputBorder(
                                            borderRadius:
                                                BorderRadius.circular(16)),
                                        hintText: 'Email',
                                        hintStyle: TextStyle(
                                            color: const Color(0x99d1d1d1)),
                                        contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                            left: 16,
                                            right: 16,
                                            top: 8,
                                            bottom: 8)),
                                  ),
                                ),
                                Container(
                                  margin: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 16),
                                  child: TextField(
                                    cursorColor: const Color(0x9932394a),
                                    keyboardType: TextInputType.phone,
                                    maxLength: 10,
                                    maxLengthEnforcement:
                                        MaxLengthEnforcement.enforced,
                                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                                        prefixIcon: Container(
                                          padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10),
                                          margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                                          height: 10,
                                          width: 65,
                                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                              borderRadius:
                                                  BorderRadius.circular(8),
                                              color: Colors.grey
                                                  .withOpacity(0.10),
                                              border: Border.all(
                                                color: Colors.black,
                                              )),
                                          child: Row(
                                            children: [
                                              Text("+1"),
                                              Icon(Icons.arrow_drop_down),
                                            ],
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                        suffixIconColor:
                                            const Color(0x9932394a),
                                        focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                          borderSide: BorderSide(
                                              color: const Color(0x9932394a)),
                                          borderRadius:
                                              BorderRadius.circular(16),
                                        ),
                                        border: OutlineInputBorder(
                                            borderRadius:
                                                BorderRadius.circular(16)),
                                        hintText: 'Phone Number',
                                        counterText: "",
                                        hintStyle: TextStyle(
                                            color: const Color(0x99d1d1d1)),
                                        contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                            left: 16,
                                            right: 16,
                                            top: 8,
                                            bottom: 8)),
                                  ),
                                ),
                                Container(
                                  margin: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 16),
                                  child: TextField(
                                    cursorColor: const Color(0x9932394a),
                                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                                        focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                          borderSide: BorderSide(
                                              color: const Color(0x9932394a)),
                                          borderRadius:
                                              BorderRadius.circular(16),
                                        ),
                                        border: OutlineInputBorder(
                                            borderRadius:
                                                BorderRadius.circular(16)),
                                        hintText: 'Username',
                                        hintStyle: TextStyle(
                                            color: const Color(0x99d1d1d1)),
                                        contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                            left: 16,
                                            right: 16,
                                            top: 8,
                                            bottom: 8)),
                                  ),
                                ),
                                Container(
                                  margin: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 20),
                                  child: TextField(
                                    cursorColor: const Color(0x9932394a),
                                    controller: password_textfield,
                                    obscureText: !_passwordVisible,
                                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                                        focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                          borderSide: BorderSide(
                                              color: const Color(0x9932394a)),
                                          borderRadius:
                                              BorderRadius.circular(16),
                                        ),
                                        border: OutlineInputBorder(
                                            borderRadius:
                                                BorderRadius.circular(16)),
                                        hintText: 'Password',
                                        hintStyle: TextStyle(
                                            color: const Color(0x99d1d1d1)),
                                        suffixIcon: IconButton(
                                          icon: Icon(
                                            // Based on passwordVisible state choose the icon
                                            _passwordVisible
                                                ? Icons.visibility
                                                : Icons.visibility_off,
                                            color: const Color(0x9932394a),
                                          ),
                                          onPressed: () {
                                            // Update the state i.e. toogle the state of passwordVisible variable
                                            setState(() {
                                              _passwordVisible =
                                                  !_passwordVisible;
                                            });
                                          },
                                        ),
                                        contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                            left: 16,
                                            right: 16,
                                            top: 8,
                                            bottom: 8)),
                                  ),
                                ),
                                Container(
                                  margin: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 20),
                                  child: TextField(
                                    cursorColor: const Color(0x9932394a),
                                    controller: confirm_password_textfield,
                                    obscureText: !_confirmpasswordVisible,
                                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                                        focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                          borderSide: BorderSide(
                                              color: const Color(0x9932394a)),
                                          borderRadius:
                                              BorderRadius.circular(16),
                                        ),
                                        border: OutlineInputBorder(
                                            borderRadius:
                                                BorderRadius.circular(16)),
                                        hintText: 'Confirm Password',
                                        hintStyle: TextStyle(
                                            color: const Color(0x99d1d1d1)),
                                        suffixIcon: IconButton(
                                          icon: Icon(
                                            // Based on passwordVisible state choose the icon
                                            _confirmpasswordVisible
                                                ? Icons.visibility
                                                : Icons.visibility_off,
                                            color: const Color(0x9932394a),
                                          ),
                                          onPressed: () {
                                            // Update the state i.e. toogle the state of passwordVisible variable
                                            setState(() {
                                              _confirmpasswordVisible =
                                                  !_confirmpasswordVisible;
                                            });
                                          },
                                        ),
                                        contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                            left: 16,
                                            right: 16,
                                            top: 8,
                                            bottom: 8)),
                                  ),
                                ),
                                Row(
                                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                                  children: [
                                    Expanded(
                                      child: ElevatedButton(
                                        onPressed: () {},
                                        style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                                          backgroundColor:
                                              const Color(0x9932394a),
                                          minimumSize:
                                              Size(double.infinity, 50),
                                          textStyle: TextStyle(
                                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                              fontSize: 18),
                                          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(
                                                20), // Adjust the value as per your requirement
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                        child: const Text("Register",
                                            style: TextStyle(
                                              color: Colors.white,
                                            )),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                                const SizedBox(
                                  height: 25,
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        )),
                  ),
            
                  Container(
                    child: TextButton(
                      onPressed: () async {},
                      child: RichText(
                        text: TextSpan(
                          children: <TextSpan>[
                            TextSpan(
                              text: "Back to",
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.black, fontSize: 15.0),
                            ),
                            TextSpan(
                              text: ' Sign In',
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                  color: Colors.black,
                                  fontSize: 15.0),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
   final confirm_password_textfield = TextEditingController();
  final password_textfield = TextEditingController();

  bool _passwordVisible = false;
  bool _confirmpasswordVisible = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Stack(
          clipBehavior: Clip.none,
          children: [
            Container(
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.4,
              color: const Color(0xff32394a),
              child: const Column(
                children: [
                  Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 55, left: 20),
                    child: Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                      children: [
                        Icon(
                          Icons.arrow_back_ios_new_outlined,
                          color: Colors.white,
                        ),
                        Text(
                          'AppName',
                          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 40, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, color: Colors.white),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          width: 10,
                          height: 10,
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Positioned(
                top: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.25 - 100,
                left: 32,
                right: 32,
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    Container(
                      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width - 64,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: const Color(0xffFFFFFF),
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                        border: Border.all(
                          color: const Color(0xffe8e8e8), // Set the border color here
                          width: 2.0, // Set the border width
                        ),
                      ),
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(32),
                      child: Column(
                        children: [
                          Container(
                            margin: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 32),
                            child: const Text(
                              'Sign Up',
                              style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 24,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          Container(
                            margin: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 16),
                            child: TextField(
                              cursorColor: const Color(0x9932394a),
                              decoration: InputDecoration(
                                  focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                    borderSide: BorderSide(color: const Color(0x9932394a)),
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16),
                                  ),
                                  border: OutlineInputBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16)),
                                  hintText: 'Full Name',
                                  hintStyle: TextStyle(color: const Color(0x99d1d1d1)),
                                  contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 16, right: 16, top: 8, bottom: 8)),
                            ),
                          ),
                          Container(
                            margin: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 16),
                            child: TextField(
                              cursorColor: const Color(0x9932394a),
                              decoration: InputDecoration(
                                  focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                    borderSide: BorderSide(color: const Color(0x9932394a)),
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16),
                                  ),
                                  border: OutlineInputBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16)),
                                  hintText: 'Email',
                                  hintStyle: TextStyle(color: const Color(0x99d1d1d1)),
                                  contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 16, right: 16, top: 8, bottom: 8)),
                            ),
                          ),
                          Container(
                            margin: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 16),
                            child: TextField(
                              cursorColor: const Color(0x9932394a),
                              keyboardType: TextInputType.phone,
                              maxLength: 10,
                              maxLengthEnforcement: MaxLengthEnforcement.enforced,
                              decoration: InputDecoration(
                                  prefixIcon: Container(
                                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10),
                                    margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                                    height: 10,
                                    width: 65,
                                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
                                      color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.10),
                                      border: Border.all(
                                        color: Colors.black,
                                      )
                                    ),
                                    child: Row(
                                      children: [
                                        Text("+1"),
                                        Icon(Icons.arrow_drop_down),
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  suffixIconColor: const Color(0x9932394a),
                                  focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                    borderSide: BorderSide(color: const Color(0x9932394a)),
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16),
                                  ),
                                  border: OutlineInputBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16)),
                                  hintText: 'Phone Number',
                                  counterText: "",
                                  hintStyle: TextStyle(color: const Color(0x99d1d1d1)),
                                  contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 16, right: 16, top: 8, bottom: 8)),
                            ),
                          ),
                          Container(
                            margin: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 16),
                            child: TextField(
                              cursorColor: const Color(0x9932394a),
                              decoration: InputDecoration(
                                  focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                    borderSide: BorderSide(color: const Color(0x9932394a)),
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16),
                                  ),
                                  border: OutlineInputBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16)),
                                  hintText: 'Username',
                                  hintStyle: TextStyle(color: const Color(0x99d1d1d1)),
                                  contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 16, right: 16, top: 8, bottom: 8)),
                            ),
                          ),
                          Container(
                            margin: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 20),
                            child: TextField(
                              cursorColor: const Color(0x9932394a),
                              controller: password_textfield,
                              obscureText: !_passwordVisible,
                              decoration: InputDecoration(
                                  focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                    borderSide: BorderSide(color: const Color(0x9932394a)),
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16),
                                  ),
                                  border: OutlineInputBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16)),
                                  hintText: 'Password',
                                  hintStyle: TextStyle(color: const Color(0x99d1d1d1)),
                                  suffixIcon: IconButton(
                                    icon: Icon(
                                      // Based on passwordVisible state choose the icon
                                      _passwordVisible ? Icons.visibility : Icons.visibility_off,
                                      color: const Color(0x9932394a),
                                    ),
                                    onPressed: () {
                                      // Update the state i.e. toogle the state of passwordVisible variable
                                      setState(() {
                                        _passwordVisible = !_passwordVisible;
                                      });
                                    },
                                  ),
                                  contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 16, right: 16, top: 8, bottom: 8)),
                            ),
                          ),
                          Container(
                            margin: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 20),
                            child: TextField(
                              cursorColor: const Color(0x9932394a),
                              controller: confirm_password_textfield,
                              obscureText: !_confirmpasswordVisible,
                              decoration: InputDecoration(
                                  focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                    borderSide: BorderSide(color: const Color(0x9932394a)),
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16),
                                  ),
                                  border: OutlineInputBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16)),
                                  hintText: 'Confirm Password',
                                  hintStyle: TextStyle(color: const Color(0x99d1d1d1)),
                                  suffixIcon: IconButton(
                                    icon: Icon(
                                      // Based on passwordVisible state choose the icon
                                      _confirmpasswordVisible ? Icons.visibility : Icons.visibility_off,
                                      color: const Color(0x9932394a),
                                    ),
                                    onPressed: () {
                                      // Update the state i.e. toogle the state of passwordVisible variable
                                      setState(() {
                                        _confirmpasswordVisible = !_confirmpasswordVisible;
                                      });
                                    },
                                  ),
                                  contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 16, right: 16, top: 8, bottom: 8)),
                            ),
                          ),
                          Row(
                            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                            children: [
                              Expanded(
                                child: ElevatedButton(
                                  onPressed: () {},
                                  style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                                    backgroundColor: const Color(0x9932394a),
                                    minimumSize: Size(double.infinity, 50),
                                    textStyle: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 18),
                                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20), // Adjust the value as per your requirement
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  child: const Text("Register",
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                        color: Colors.white,
                                      )),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                          const SizedBox(
                            height: 25,
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                    Container(
                      margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 32),
                      child: TextButton(
                        onPressed: () async {
                          Navigator.of(context).pop();
                        },
                        child: RichText(
                          text: TextSpan(
                            children: <TextSpan>[
                              TextSpan(
                                text: "Back to",
                                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 15.0),
                              ),
                              TextSpan(
                                text: ' Sign In',
                                style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, color: Colors.black, fontSize: 15.0),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                )),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Try  this  code

Comment: Could you add some more explanation to your post?

Comment: your issue has   been fixed  UI  issue and Mobile   Number Field or  App Bar Issue  Fixed

Comment: The code you provided having a UI issue in nexus 5X please check.

Comment: using  Expand  Widget  for   Your  White   Container  your  Issue Has  been  Fixed